# Are questions posted on weekends at a disadvantage?

Tags: discussion, questions

When a person such as me is bored on a Friday or Saturday night and decides to spend it surfing Pr.SE, is a question they post going to be at a disadvantage for attention due to the smaller audience visiting the site on the weekend? I've noticed that weekends don't have a lot of activity but have a steady enough flow of questions to push questions from a Friday or Saturday off the page by Monday, when the visitors start to ramp up again.

I would hope the Community user would be smart enough to help this, but I don't know if that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to have the most amount of eyes on your question, then yes, it is at a disadvantage to post over the weekend.  BUT that doesn't mean that your question won't get answered.  This current weekend, a bunch of questions were asked and EVERY single question that was answerable, had several very good answers to them within a couple of hours.

Did the posters get as much Rep as they would have on a Monday at 14:00 or 16:00 GMT (both Europe and US are typically online during those times)?  Probably not.  Is the goal to get an answer to a question or to build Rep?

Comment: That's a good point. I suppose I would say the goal *is* to get the most amount of eyes on it, at least if it's a subjective question; having more eyes means more answers, and better chance of getting the one you need.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting questions have a life longer that a few days, so it doesn't matter when you ask it.